# Component icons in Delphi 11 Alexandria

Tags: delphi, background, components, icons

Why do my component icons show a magenta background in Delphi 11 Alexandria?
In Delphi previous versions they were understood as transparent.

[image]

Comment: Probably you just need to update to alpha transparency

Comment: Delphi 11 doesn't honor the bottom right pixel color as transparency color. You have either to use an image file format supporting alpha channel with transparency or replace the magenta color by light grey (or other good looking color) so that the icons looks OK under Delphi 11.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone's advice!
Actually, I solved this issue by rebuilding the DCR files using the BRCC32. :)

PS: Further research made me realize what was causing this issue: When I build a DCR file with two resources for the same component (say, TMYCOMP and TMYCOMP16), I get the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).